# Cambiar el color de los componentes mientras tienen el puntero encima

Tags: java, java-swing

La mayoría de componentes swing cambian de color cuando tienen el puntero encima. Sin embargo quisiera personalizar dicho color (siempre se pintan azul), he buscado información pero no he encontrado nada.
Particularmente me interesa saber como hacerlo con los JButton, con los elementos de un JMenuBar, JMenuItem y los elementos de un jList.

[image: Boton]

[image: JMenuBar y JMenuItem]

[image: Elementos de un JList]

Comment: Supongo que tendrás que sobrescribir el método onMouseOver del item del elemento que quieras modificar.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, si lo que quieres es cambiar el color del botón o su estilo al pasar el ratón por arriba debes usar los métodos **mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)** y **mouseExited(mouseEvent)** que traen los **JComponents**.

Un ejemplo: Se cambia el color del fondo del componente **JButton**

```
JButton buscarButton = new JButton("Buscar");
        buscarButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buscarButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        buscarButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                buscarButton.setBackground((Color.BLUE));
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                buscarButton.setBackground((Color.WHITE));
            }
        });
        buscarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                buscar();
            }
        });
```